# error The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, pdf, ms-word

In this i am trying to convert word to pdf file. But i am getting an error
 *"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".*

```
    public Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDocuments { get; set; }

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application apword = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    try
    {
        if (uploadFInput.HasFile)
        {
            targetPathip = Server.MapPath(Path.GetFileName(uploadFInput.PostedFile.FileName));

            if (File.Exists(targetPathip))
            {
                File.Delete(targetPathip);
            }

            string Extentsion_path = Path.GetExtension(targetPathip);
            string Filename_path = Path.GetFileName(targetPathip);
            if (Extentsion_path == ".doc" || Extentsion_path == ".docx")
            {
                uploadFInput.SaveAs(targetPathip);
                LblFleip.Text = targetPathip;

                //wordDocuments = apword.Documents.Open(Filename_path);
                wordDocuments = apword.Documents.Open(Filename_path);
                // wordDocuments = apword.Documents.Open(targetPathip);

                wordDocuments.ExportAsFixedFormat(Filename_path, WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                apword.Documents.Close(Filename_path);
            }
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(targetPathip);
            uploadFInput.SaveAs(targetPathip);
            LblFleip.Text = targetPathip;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        apword = null;
        return;
    }
```

Is there anything missing in my code while converting? Can anyone tell me how to convert word to pdf.

Comment: `wordDocuments = apword.Documents.Open(Filename_path) ..
 wordDocuments.ExportAsFixedFormat(Filename_path, X)` - same filename looks *very* suspicious.

Comment: @ user2246674 it had worked in windows form same code ....

Comment: The actual word document isn't opened on your desktop when you run this code is it?

Comment: are you sure that is the actual line that it crashes on, have you stepped through? (you should have a using block around the apwords declaration

Comment: File.Delete(targetPathip); problem is in this line . if the file already exists then it should delete . But in that place i am getting an error The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Comment: file if exists it is opened. this code worked for if pdf file is the input. but with word i got error

Comment: R U able to solve this issue ?  Even I am getting this issue ! :(

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to determine the process which is holding the file open.

To find this out you need to download Process Explorer from SysInternals (now part of Microsoft).

This will allow you to search all the processes to find out which ones have open handles to your file.

Of course it may be that the file conflict is related to a less obvious file such as a configuration or lock file. In that case Process Monitor (also from SysInternals) should allow you to see what is failing.

Both are brilliant tools and once you have used them they will become part of your armoury.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code the first time - it's possible will be okay. But it's obvious that file is not disposed properly. Standart .net *GC* doesn't works on `Interop` objects correctly. So, few hints:
1) Do not make public properties with `Interop.Word.Document` or `Interop.Word.Application`. Use them in your methods and dispose ASAP.
2) The second reason to close `Application` ASAP is that RPC server has timeout. If you keep `Application` open for a while it will be automatically disconnected from RPC server and you'll not be able to use it.

With this in mind, you have to call `apword.Quit();` in `finally` statement, not in `catch` and `apword = null` alone isn't sufficient.
If application has been shut down with error - kill word process for sure.
And don't forget to call `wordDocuments.Close(ref SaveChanges)` before leaving the method.

Answer (score -1):

The variable contains filename with extension, so you are trying save document over the opened document. Add an axtension:

```
 wordDocuments.ExportAsFixedFormat(Filename_path + ".pdf",
     WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
```

I guess that line *File.Delete(targetPathip);* isn't the problem, maybe in second run, because application holds the file open from first run (see task manager).

Comment: I had wondered if this was a second run through, this could be resolved by disposing of apword correctly if this is the case

Answer (score -1):

Got a problem like this once, try a close on your file before your open (sounds stupid but worked for me...).

```
apword.Documents.Close(Filename_path);
wordDocuments = apword.Documents.Open(Filename_path);
```

Comment: exception :@3wic  This method or property is not available because a document window is not active.

Answer (score -2):

You just have to add

```
using System.Threading;
```

at the top of cs page..
And add

```
Thread.SpinWait(6000);
```

at the top of text where it is showing you an error.

Try this and if u need any help tell me.

Comment: I would advise against this... Seems like it will just delay the problem

Comment: @mitesh this would simply delay it.a nd if the file of the pdf or the word is very big. which is difficult.

Comment: i agree with @sayse this will delay

Comment: I had tried and it had worked for me. but i had make it work for making a copy of my image and than make it to delete afterwords